# How to test that a component calls a function prop with another component as argument?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-props, react-testing-library

I have a component that receives a function as a prop and passes a rendered element to it, on mount:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.onHeaderChange(<button>Back</button>)
  }, [])

  return (<div>My Component</div>)
}
```

I want to write a test for checking that the back button is passed:

```
test("it renders the back button", () => {
  const onHeaderChange = jest.fn()
  const { getByText } = render(
    <MyComponent {...props} onHeaderChange={onHeaderChange} />
  )

  expect(onHeaderChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith("How to test for the back button here?")
})
```

But I'm not sure what the jest / react testing library syntax is for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions:

**Option 1.** Passing JSX to the `toHaveBeenCalledWith` method is enough. Why? Because JSX is syntax sugar for `React.createElement()` method. Code written with JSX will be converted to use `React.createElement()`. The return value of it is just a JavaScript object.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export function MyComponent(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.onHeaderChange(<button>Back</button>);
  }, []);

  return <div>My Component</div>;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { MyComponent } from '.';

describe('71995270', () => {
  test('it renders the back button', () => {
    const onHeaderChange = jest.fn();
    render(<MyComponent onHeaderChange={onHeaderChange} />);

    const expectedElement = React.createElement('button', null, 'Back');
    console.log('expectedElement: ', expectedElement);
    expect(onHeaderChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedElement);
    expect(onHeaderChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith(<button>Back</button>);
  });
});
```

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71995270/index.test.tsx (14.782 s)
  71995270
    ✓ it renders the back button (42 ms)

  console.log
    expectedElement:  {
      '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
      type: 'button',
      key: null,
      ref: null,
      props: { children: 'Back' },
      _owner: null,
      _store: {}
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/71995270/index.test.tsx:11:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.871 s
```

**Option 2.** Using `mockImplementation` to mock `onHeaderChange` function and get the `button` element in test case, `render` it and assert.

```
test('it renders the back button - 2', () => {
  let buttonElement;
  const onHeaderChange = jest.fn().mockImplementation((element) => {
    buttonElement = element;
  });
  render(<MyComponent onHeaderChange={onHeaderChange} />);

  const { getByRole } = render(buttonElement);
  expect(getByRole('button')).toHaveTextContent('Back');
});
```

Comment: thanks, I like the 2nd option since I can test for the content of the rendered element